# renderAs PDF: Margin Problems

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf

Good Day,
I'm having trouble with renderAs in a Visualforce PDF
  developed a HTML to generate a pdf from a custom object, this would cover that contains HTML fullscreen but visulforce are putting margins and this is causing my HTML if unconfigure all, tried to put

```
 <style type="text/css">
  @ page {
    margin: 0in;
    margin: 0px;
    margin: 0cm;
  }
</ style>
```

But nothing works. Could you help me?

Comment: What does your <apex:page> look like? Are you overriding the Salesforce CSS styles?

Comment: Yes, i'm using my customized CSS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess but I think you might have a small syntax issue. Remove the space between the @ and page

Example:

```
@page {
    size: 21.0cm 29.7cm;
    margin-top: 2.0cm;
    margin-left: 0cm;
    margin-right: 1.5cm;
    margin-bottom: 2cm;
}
```

Comment: Also - just found this which may be a nice resource for building PDFs: http://www.antennahouse.com/CSSInfo/CSS-Page-Tutorial-en.pdf

Comment: Very Nice man. Just Work! I Think its a small syntax issue because the space

Comment: Woot! Got to love those syntax issues. I dream of the day when the interface knows what we MEANT in our heads not what we actually typed:)

Comment: Can use [W3C CSS Validation Service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input+with_options) and paste your CSS into it and choose level 2.  Would've given you `Parse Error Lexical error at line 1, column 2. Encountered: " " (32), after : "@"`